# How can I set CSS class for django-filter generated elements?

Tags: django, django-filter

I am using django-filter(little library for django elements filtering). And I want to know how can I add some CSS classes to that generated HTML elements. Here is code for filters.py. Thank you from Armenia nice person :)

```
class Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    CHOICES = (
        ('ascending', 'По дате (А-Я)'),
        ('descending', 'По дате (Я-А)'),
    )
    CHOICES2 = (
        ('price_low', 'По цене по возрастанию'),
        ('price_high', 'По цене по убыванию'),
    )

orderDate = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, method='filter_by_date', label='')
orderPrice = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES2, method='filter_by_price', label='')
category = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='category', queryset=Category.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = {
        'price': ['gt', 'lt'],
        'category': [],
    }

def filter_by_date(self, queryset, name, value):
    expr = 'date' if value == 'ascending' else '-date'
    return queryset.order_by(expr)

def filter_by_price(self, queryset, name, value):
    expr = 'price' if value == 'price_low' else '-price'
    return queryset.order_by(expr)
```

Comment: You can create a form class and set it in the Meta class of the filter, check [this](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#custom-forms-using-form) in django-filters documentation. Also a great library that I might recommend for rendering forms with css, etc in the template is [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/).

Comment: Salam any other ways? ARMENIA)

Comment: You may try overriding __init_\_ and then adding css attribute to the forms field from there. `self.form.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'myfieldclass'})`